# SQL - Query to seperate single column and create new columns based on column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

Sorry, if the title is horrible.  Have a table T.  With a column Name, Num, and Status that either contains a I, O, or S.

Ex:

```
Name  Num  Status
Bob   1     I
Bob   2     O
Bob   3     O
John  4     I
John  5     S
Joe   6     O
```

Want result to look like:

```
Name  Num  I  O  S
Bob   1    x 
Bob   2       x
Bob   3       X
John  4    X
John 5           X
```

Thanks!

Edit: Follow up question.

```
Name    Num  I  O  S
Bob      1   x 
Bob      1      x
Bob      2      X
```

Need result:

```
Name    Num  I  O  S
Bob     1    X  X
Bob     2       X
```

EDIT 2: Actual Query:

```
SELECT Name, Card_Nmbr,

[Out]  = case when d.Status='I' then 'X' else '' end,
[In]  = case when d.Status='O' then 'X' else '' end,
[Sales]  = case when d.Status='S' then 'X' else '' end
FROM [PCOdb].[dbo].[GC_Header] as h
INNER JOIN GC_Detail as d on h.GC_TransNmbr = d.GC_TransNmbr
INNER JOIN GC_Master as m on d.GCM_Nmbr = m.GCM_Nmbr
INNER JOIN Galaxy1.dbo.GxUsers as u on h.UserID = u.UserID
WHERE GC_TransDate between '11/29/16' and dateadd(day,1, '11/29/16')
Group BY Card_Nmbr, Name
```

Comment: EDIT 2:  Actual Query;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple case statement would help here

```
Select Name
      ,Num
      ,[I]  = case when [Status]='I' then 'X' else '' end
      ,[O]  = case when [Status]='O' then 'X' else '' end
      ,[S]  = case when [Status]='S' then 'X' else '' end
 From  YourTable
```

> **EDIT to handle multiple rows**

```
Select Name
      ,Num
      ,[I]  = max(case when [Status]='I' then 'X' else '' end)
      ,[O]  = max(case when [Status]='O' then 'X' else '' end)
      ,[S]  = max(case when [Status]='S' then 'X' else '' end)
 From  YourTable
 Group By Name,Num
```

> **Edit 2 - Full Query  (Assuming the Joins are doing what you need)**

```
SELECT Name
      ,Card_Nmbr
      ,[Out]   = max(case when d.[Status]='I' then 'X' else '' end)
      ,[In]    = max(case when d.[Status]='O' then 'X' else '' end)
      ,[Sales] = max(case when d.[Status]='S' then 'X' else '' end)
 FROM  [PCOdb].[dbo].[GC_Header] as h
 JOIN  GC_Detail as d on h.GC_TransNmbr = d.GC_TransNmbr
 JOIN  GC_Master as m on d.GCM_Nmbr = m.GCM_Nmbr
 JOIN  Galaxy1.dbo.GxUsers as u on h.UserID = u.UserID
 WHERE GC_TransDate between '2016-11-29' and DateAdd(DD,1,'2016-11-29')
 Group BY Card_Nmbr, Name
```

Comment: Thank you!  I have a quick follow up; now lets say that Bob has two items with Num=2, one with Status O, One with Status I.  What if I need to show one column then like so :    Bob     2      X     X (where there are two X's, under the I and O columns)  Thanks again!

Comment: @escapeclaws Just so I am clear, do you want Bob to have 1 row with an O and an I selected?

Comment: Yes, I added an edit above for clarification.  Again thank you!

Comment: Thank you again.  When I try the group by I am getting an error: "Column 'GC_Detail.Status' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause"  I can post the actual query if that helps.  I am very unfamiliar with this process.

Comment: @escapeclaws sure. just edit your question with the full query

Comment: Edited above with actual query

Comment: @escapeclaws See Edit 2

Comment: One thousand internet high fives!  Thank you!  That worked perfectly.  If it's not too much trouble, could you give me the 1 sentence explanation of max in this scenario.  (I will google it regardless)

Comment: @escapeclaws  The max is an aggregation function.  We're grabbing the max value of the condition by name, number  ('X' or '')  X wins.

Comment: @escapeclaws  A good place to start  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_max.asp

Answer (score 1):

Use [Case](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) expression.

**Demo:**

```
Create table #temp
        (Name  varchar (10), 
        Num int , 
        [Status] char(1))

insert into #temp values ('Bob' ,  '1'  ,   'I')
insert into #temp values ('Bob'  , '2'  ,   'O')
insert into #temp values ('Bob'  , '3'  , 'O')
insert into #temp values ('John' , '4'  , 'I')
insert into #temp values ('John' , '5'  ,'S')
insert into #temp values ('Joe' ,  '6'  , 'O')



select Name,
        Num, 
        [I]  = case 
                when [Status] ='I' 
                then 'X' 
                else '' 
                end
      ,[O]  = case 
                when [Status] ='O' 
                then 'X' 
                else '' 
                end
      ,[S]  = case when [Status] ='S' 
                then 'X' 
                else '' 
                end
from #temp

drop table #temp
```

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012 and Later you can use [`IIF (Transact-SQL)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213574.aspx) function too.

```
Select Name 
      ,Num
      ,IIF([Status] = 'I' , 'X', '' ) AS [I]
      ,IIF([Status] = 'O' , 'X', '' ) AS [O]
      ,IIF([Status] = 'S' , 'X', '' ) AS [S]
FROM TableName
```