# Query to return new columns based on the data in a single column

Tags: sql, oracle

I saw this post ([SQL - Query to seperate single column and create new columns based on column data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40895683/sql-query-to-seperate-single-column-and-create-new-columns-based-on-column-dat)) and wanted to comment on it, however, I don't have enough rep. I want to do the exact same thing, but I want to sum the values in the column(s) that are created for the case statements.

Comment: Please post sample data and expected output

Comment: That question is tagged SQL Server. You tagged yours Oracle (or the web site tagged it for you and you didn't change it - either because you are indeed using Oracle or because you are not familiar with tags and you didn't see what the site did for you automatically). Please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply sum on case like this(column names assumed):

```
select 
    name,
    sum(case when status = 'A' then value end) SUM_A,
    sum(case when status = 'B' then value end) SUM_B,
    sum(case when status = 'C' then value end) SUM_C,
    sum(case when status = 'D' then value end) SUM_D
from your_table
group by name;
```

Comment: What is 'value' here?

Comment: @Ryan the column you want to sum

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I realized I actually had to count the values so rather than Sum I used Count(distinct(. Appreciate the help.